# how to increase maximum number of connections to database?

Tags: database

my server has CENTOS as Operating System,and uses apache as the web server.database software is MariaDB. server has 64 Gb of RAM, but once the number of daily visitors exceeds 12k,i get "error establishing a database connection. 
can anyone tell me how i should increase "Maximum No. of Connections"? 
It is currently 151.

Comment: BTW, I'm using Wordpress to power my website. can sb tell me exactly what code i should add to what part of my server to increase number of database connections?

Comment: You should implement proper caching on your site.

Comment: I've got caching plugin set up and i also use cloudflare to protect my website, but still when concurrent users increase in number, i get "error establishing a database connection"

Comment: Requests for product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic because they attract low quality, opinionated and spam answers, and the answers become obsolete quickly. Instead, describe the business problem you are working on, the research you have done, and the steps taken so far to solve it.

Answer (score 4):

Not a direct answer but something to think of. Your programming is RIDICULOUSLY bad. You indicate that you have more than 1% of your visitors active on a database at once. Note that I do not mean "concurrent visitors" or concurrent page operations - i mean concurrent db operations. That is a VERY high number.

12000 visitors PER DAY should at no point require 151 database connections. Not even 20. You seem to keep them open forever, possibly leaking them and not closing them at all.

Obviously wrong if every visitor does extreme long operations that require minute long sql statements. Which I somehow bet is not the case.

Comment: google analytics shows that at some points in day i have over 200  simultaneous users on the site, my CMS is wordpress, when number of visitors exceeds a certain point i get "error establishing a database connection".

Comment: That means nothing - because it does ont say "active at this moment": 200 concurrent sessions means (just ROUGH ideas) around maybe 4 concurrent page refreshes, which runs down to 0.4 database connections, as scaling numbers that I normally use. If that is a site with a CMS, you ignore the use of caching, and something in there is written by somoene REALLY not competent, keeping a session alive per user or some of that ridiculous beginner mistakes.

Comment: ok, I got your point. do you know how i can increase max number of connections in MariaDB? it shows as 151 now.

Answer (score 2):

increase `max_connections` in `my.cnf` config file

https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/server-system-variables/#max_connections
https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/handling-too-many-connections/

Comment: can you please tell me exactly what code i should include in my.cnf file?

Comment: @juliaann We don't spoon-feed here. Read the documentation for the systems you're using and figure it out.